# Save many to many fields in django view in a certein order

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a ManyToMany model in django app:

```py
class Colors(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Cars(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Lote(models.Model):
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Cars)
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Cars)
```

Im trying to save a new `Lote()` with two pk lists:

```py
colors_pk = [1,2,3]
cars_pk = [3,1,2]
```

My question is: if i save `Lote()` instance like this:

```py
lote = Lote(adress='Some address')
lote.save()
lote.cars.add(cars_pk)
lote.color.add(colors_pk)
```

will the colors and cars be saved on m2m field in the same order as the list? because the order of the lists is important - `colors_pk` and `cars_pk` are related by index i.e. car 3 is linked to color 1.

So how should I do it?

Comment: Btw, generally model names are singular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would redesign your models as such:

```
class Color(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    color = models.ManyToManyField(Color)


class Lot(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cars = models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

This leaves Cars related to Lote, and Colors by extension, but ensures that Colors are properly linked to Cars.

Comment: you probably meant `ManyToManyField(Colors)`, though this design is also wrong anyway

Comment: I did, thanks. What's wrong about this design, though? It's hard to infer what OP's use case is specifically, but this still meets the needs of the original design without requiring specific ordering, no?

Comment: I take that back, you're right. I was thinking it would make more sense to add a `foreignKey` from colors to Cars but now I realize it's actually better your way (because you only define a color once). It's just my knee-jerk reaction to try and avoid `ManyToMany`. So you got a +1 from me. Also, unrelated: it would be nice to fix his grammer mistakes (`Lot` instead of `Lote` and `address` instead of `adress`)

Comment: Thanks. My initial comment on the question also suggested `ForeignKey` but since I wasn't sure exactly what OP was asking, decided to keep `ManyToMany`. However, if a Car only had one Color, a ForeignKey from Car to Color would still work without having duplicate Color entries. I did fix the class/var names, as well. I did not realize `Lote` was intended to be `Lot`, good catch :)

Comment: I meant a foreignKey from color to car (seems more reasonable not to duplicate brands), but eh, you get my point :-)